# Testing Django Rest Framework: how to test hyperlink relations?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a true unit test for a customized DjangoRestFramework Hyperlinked related field. But I cannot seem to get around this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "relatedtestmodel-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

And here is the unit test, stripped down to simplify the example:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

from api_tests.models import APITestModel, RelatedTestModel
from api_tests.serializers import APITestModelSerializer


def dummy_view(request, pk):
    pass


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'/path/is/irrelevant/', dummy_view, name='relatedtestmodel-detail')
]


@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='tests.test_relations')
class HyperlinkedRelatedFieldTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.parent = APITestModel.objects.create()
        self.child = RelatedTestModel.objects.create(parent=self.parent)
        assert self.child.parent.id == self.parent.id

    def test_to_internal_value_correct_error_message(self):
        queryset = APITestModel.objects.all()
        serializer = APITestModelSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': None})
        expected = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
        self.assertEqual(serializer.data, expected)
```

I more or less lifted the test from https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/tests/test_relations_hyperlink.py, because I figured who knows best how to unit test DRF than the makers of DRF? But as it stands, my test refuses to run. The error is raised during the test, when I attempt to access `serializer.data` for the assert.

Notice in particular that I override the settings with a custom urlpatterns (which is this same file, hence the urlpatterns at the top). So I don't understand why DRF thinks that url name doesn't exist - I can clearly see that my url conf in fact has ONLY that view name! I've even gone so far as to edit my actual URL conf and replace it with the single, named, dummy url pattern shown here, and removedthe settings override, just to be sure that it wasn't that the override_settings simply wasn't working, but even then I get the same error.

To my eye, the dummy url pattern is exactly the same as how DRF did it in their tests. Anyone have any ideas what is going on?

A bit more requested context:

api_tests.models:

```
from django.db import models

class APITestModel(models.Model):
    pass

class RelatedTestModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        APITestModel,
        related_name='children',
        related_query_name='child'
    )
```

I do not have access to the traceback at this time, but I can confirm it did not pass through any of my code - it was all isolated to the DjangoRestFramework code, basically exclusively relations.py

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add the definiiton of `APITestModelSerializer`. Also, please add the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

### A few things this question is lacking

1. No definition of `APITestModelSerializer`
2. `RelatedTestModel` is not used in the test and therefore irrelevant for the example
3. No error stacktrace
4. No "useful" expected dict for the asserts
5. `APITestModel` has no fields so it can't be serialized (your test shouldn't even have run)

### Minor things but still relevant

1. You are creating specific instances of `APITestModel` and `RelatedTestModel` in the setUp but in the test you serialize all instances of APITestModel
2. The line `assert self.child.parent.id == self.parent.id` should not be in the setUp. It should be in a separate test

### My changes

1. I deleted all irrelevant information for this question mentioned above
2. I added an integer field to `APITestModel`
3. I changed the urlpatterns element from url(...) to path(...)
4. I added a regex to the relative path
5. The serializer is a subclass of `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and includes fields "url" and "year"
6. My project and app `urls.py` files are the "stock" ones (not shown here) to emphasize that this test resolves the path in isolation.
7. Changed `@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='tests.test_relations')` to `@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)`

## Code

### models.py

```
from django.db import models


class APITestModel(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from api.models import APITestModel


class APITestModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = APITestModel
        fields = ["url", "year"]
```

### test_serializers.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.urls import path

from api.models import APITestModel
from api.serializers import APITestModelSerializer

urlpatterns = [
    path('whateveryouwant/<int:pk>/', lambda request: None, name='apitestmodel-detail'),
]


@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)
class HyperlinkedRelatedFieldTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Populate db with APITestModel instances
        _ = APITestModel.objects.create(year=1960)
        _ = APITestModel.objects.create(year=1961)
        _ = APITestModel.objects.create(year=1962)

    def test_to_internal_value_correct_error_message(self):
        queryset = APITestModel.objects.all()
        serializer = APITestModelSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': None})
        expected = [
            {'url': '/whateveryouwant/1/', 'year': 1960},
            {'url': '/whateveryouwant/2/', 'year': 1961},
            {'url': '/whateveryouwant/3/', 'year': 1962},
        ]
        self.assertEqual(serializer.data, expected)
```

The other files in the project are the default ones created automatically by django + djangorestframework.

For future readers, I created a github project with this working code and can be found here: https://github.com/Alechan/drf_test_hyperlink_relations